# In Excel VBA, how do I select rows containing specific values in a column and hide them?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying for the life of me to figure out Excel VBA but I've been getting nowhere.

Here's what I'm needing to do:

Have a list of thousands of entries - each one corresponding to a ticket for a customer. Columns include information like client name (Column B), # of minutes worked on per ticket (Column I), etc.

We're trying to make a macro that totals the # minutes of worked on for all tickets of a specific client in a new row directly below, then hide all of those rows. 
The end result should be only seeing a row containing "Total -client name here-" in the name column, then the total number of minutes in the # of minutes column.

The previous macros I've done aren't dynamic and were done via recordings within excel (which obviously don't work the way I wanted to, apparently).

Programming isn't my forte, and all this has been doing is making me want to pull my hair out. Any help?

Comment: check: Excel >> Menu >> Data >> Outline >> Subtotals

Comment: Do you need VBA? Wouldn't a Pivot Table work for this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you'd be better off using a database like Access.  You can enter all your information into a table and then write a query to find what you need.  If you don't want to use Access, we'll need a better idea of what you're trying to do.